# I've found this 3-letter game, but when I tried to run the program, my screen says that the 7th line has an error

Tags: python

My screen says that the 7th line has a syntax error. Any ideas why?

```
words = []

game = "play"

while game == "play":

new = input("Enter a 3-letter word: ")

if len(new) > 3 or len(new) < 3:

    print("That's not a 3-letter word.")

else:
    if new in words:
        game = "over"
        print("You already said that word, Game Over.")

        print("You know", len(words), "3-letter words.
```

Comment: Can you share the exact error you're getting?

Comment: `new = input("Enter a 3-letter word: ")` should be indented

Comment: also why do you create empty lines in between?

Comment: Also, note that `len(new) > 3 or len(new) < 3` can be simply written `len(new) != 3`

Comment: @cyberhenson Could you check if the proposed answer solves your issue? If so you may accept it.

Answer (score 1):

Python uses indentation instead of parenthesis or brackets to mark the beginning and end of statements such as if, or for or in this case while. All you need to do is to include a tab in all the lines that are supposed to be inside the while statement and that should work fine:

```
words = []

game = "play"

while game == "play":

    new = input("Enter a 3-letter word: ")

    if len(new) > 3 or len(new) < 3:

        print("That's not a 3-letter word.")

    else:
        if new in words:
            game = "over"
            print("You already said that word, Game Over.")

            print("You know", len(words), "3-letter words.")
```